# C# Prism : Setting ViewModel property from a controller (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

The ViewModel:

```
public class ConnectionStatusViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private string _txtConn;

    public string TextConn
    {
        get { return _txtConn; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _txtConn, value); }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="k7Bot.Login.Views.ConnectionStatus"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" Width="300">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">    
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,0">connected:</Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextConn}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="22" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The View:

```
public partial class ConnectionStatus : UserControl
{
    public ConnectionStatus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In another module, I have an event listener, that eventually runs this code:

```
ConnectionStatusViewModel viewModel = _connectionView.DataContext as ConnectionStatusViewModel;
if (viewModel != null)
{
    viewModel.TextConn = "Testing 123";

}
```

The code runs but the `TextConn` is updated and does not display in the UI

Comment: Are you sure that your `_connectionView` instance is the one that's displayed? And why do you use the `ViewModelLocator` when you have the view model injected anyway?

Comment: Removed the view injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, this code works, the issue was that I was running this code:

```
ConnectionStatusViewModel viewModel = _connectionView.DataContext as ConnectionStatusViewModel;
if (viewModel != null)
{
    viewModel.TextConn = "Testing 123";

}
```

before the view was actually activated. Silly, but maybe it will help someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure TextConn does not update? Because it can update but the display could not change. You should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and after you make any changes to TextConn call the implemented OnPropertyChanged("TextConn"); or whatever you name the function. This will tell the UI that the value has changed and it needs to update.

Comment: Possible that the UI is not updating only... Do u have to implement INotifyProperyChanged for the UI to update ?

Comment: you are right, it is updating, just not displaying in UI

Comment: `BindableBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`... you should make sure that the view model you're updating is actually the bound one.

Answer (score 0):

The UserControl's `DataContext` gets its value when the UC is initialized. Then you get a copy of the DataContext, cast it to a view model object, and change the property. I don't believe that the UC gets its original DataContext updated in this scenario.

Probably you need to use a message mediator to communicated changes between different modules.